# multiple nodes with same name as rows

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

This may look like a duplicate, but what I can find are getting multiple rows from nodes with elements inside, like

```
<products>
  <product>
    <image>url1</image>
  </product>
  <product>
    <image>url1</image>
  </product>
</products>
```

What I have is an XML-field in a table (with PLU as an integer)

```
<product>
  <images>
    <image>url1</image>
    <image>url2</image>
    <image>url3</image>
  </images>
</product>
```

I want

```
image
-----
url1
url2
url3
```

I tried

```
select a.image.value('image','nvarchar(max)') as image 
from products r
cross apply r.xml.nodes('/product/images') a(image) where PLU='8019'
```

but that gives

```
XQuery [products.xml.value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), 
found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'
```

As I want the value of each node, not of subnodes, I tried

```
select a.image.value('.','nvarchar(max)') ...
```

but that gave me only one row with `url1url2url3` all urls concatenated.

```
select a.image.value('image[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

gives only `url1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLease try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<product>
  <images>
    <image>url1</image>
    <image>url2</image>
    <image>url3</image>
  </images>
</product>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ID
    , c.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS image_url
FROM @tbl
CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/product/images/image') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----------+
| ID | image_url |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | url1      |
|  1 | url2      |
|  1 | url3      |
+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter solution than Yitzhak Khabhinsky is this by Martin Boje Carpentier elsewhere, but I'll award the points to Yitzhak

```
select a.image.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as image 
from products r
cross apply r.xml.nodes('/product/images/*') a(image) where PLU='8019'
```